# How to set two buttons on one form html&php

Tags: php, html

This form should calculate numbers and save
Now there are two buttons One is call Calculator and two call Save
If I press Calculator
I get the form action is going to file name save.php And I do not want it that way
How can I set it up that button do something else
Example

Calculator = Calculator

Save = save.php

Is it possible to set it 
Because it is one form
Thanks to anyone who can help

```
<?php
error_reporting (0);
$NUM = $_POST["NUM"];
$NUM2 = $_POST["NUM2"];
$NUM = "$NUM";
$NUM2 = "$NUM2";
$subtotal= $NUM+$NUM2;
?>

<form action="save.php" method="POST" name="Calculator">
<p>
<input name="NUM" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["NUM"]; ?>" />
</p>
<p>+</p>
<p>
<input name="NUM2" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST["NUM2"]; ?>" />
</p>
<p>
<input name="subtotal" type="text" value="<?php echo "$subtotal";?>" />
 </p>
<p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Calculator" />
 <p>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have all the logic in a single PHP script (no need to direct to a different script depending on the button). If the logic is complicated, use include statements in order to separate the code.

Name the buttons differently:

```
<input name="calculator_submit" type="submit" value="Calculator" />
<input name="save_submit" type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Then in PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['calculator_submit'])) {
  // ...
} else if (isset($_GET['save_submit'])) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

If you really need different PHP script, then you'll have to go with Javascript (function will change the form action when a submit is clicked).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are now using two submit buttons, both will submit the form and go to save.php.

Make your "calculator" button an input type=button instead of submit, and handle it via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI:

HTML5 allows to define a different form target URL by specifying the [`formaction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-formaction) attribut on a submit button – but [browser support is lousy as of now](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/HTML/Element/button.html#Compatibility).

Answer (score -1):

Form and Buttons

```
<input name="submit" type="button" onclick="submitForm('Calculator')" value="Calculator" />
<input name="submit" type="button" onclick="submitForm('Save.php')" value="Save" />
```

Some jquery:

```
function submitForm(path) {
    $('#Calculator').attr('action', path);
    $('#Calculator').submit();
}
```

Comment: -1 for the embedded onclick attribute. If you use jQuery anyway, don't pollute the markup.

Comment: You're right @MarvinLabs, despite your correctness, this is cleaner and easier to understand for somebody that does not have the knowledge you or I have. But Marvin is right, there are shorter ways, there are also more cluttered ways as well.